# What is [original] in appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed to write my own appendTo in jQuery and hence i had to refer to the jQuery source ,I saw the following code in the jQuery source:

```
function (selector) {
    var elems, i = 0,
        ret = [],
        insert = jQuery(selector),
        last = insert.length - 1;

    for (; i <= last; i++) {
        elems = i === last ? this : this.clone(true);
        jQuery(insert[i])[original](elems);

        // Modern browsers can apply jQuery collections as arrays, but oldIE needs a .get()
        push.apply(ret, elems.get());
    }

    return this.pushStack(ret);
}
```

Now i see the following line inside the jQuery code for appendTo:

```
 jQuery(insert[i])[original](elems);
```

What is `[original]` over here ?

Comment: A link to the src file you are referencing would help. It must be something defined in a scope available to that function.

Comment: @KevinB http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.appendTo

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11.2/src/manipulation.js#L717 is what i meant. The real source. :) Looking there it's relatively obvious what `original` is.

Comment: This snippet calls other jQuery methods. You don't need to convert this snippet to a non-jQuery equivalent snippet for just creating a method that appends an element to another element,  otherwise you have to define many jQuery equivalent methods/properties.

Comment: @Vohuman , i am ready to do that ! , i would like to know what `[original]` is .

Comment: To do what exactly? Do you have a constructor that works like `jQuery` constructor? I.E., are you trying to write a library that works like jQuery?  What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The [site you linked](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.appendTo) only shows the source of the function, *without* its surrounding scope (through `Function.prototype.toString`). When comparing with the [actual source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5fe76c663f8a4986af62edb434a1708c006d0b21/src/manipulation.js#L436), you can see that the `original` variable comes from an outer scope:

```
jQuery.each({
    appendTo: "append", // <<< This key-value pair...
    prependTo: "prepend",
    insertBefore: "before",
    insertAfter: "after",
    replaceAll: "replaceWith"
}, function( name, original ) { // <<< ...is bound to these arguments
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( selector ) { // <<< The function from the OP
        var elems,
            ret = [],
            insert = jQuery( selector ),
            last = insert.length - 1,
            i = 0;

        for ( ; i <= last; i++ ) {
            elems = i === last ? this : this.clone( true );
            jQuery( insert[ i ] )[ original ]( elems );

            // Support: Android<4.1, PhantomJS<2
            // .get() because push.apply(_, arraylike) throws on ancient WebKit
            push.apply( ret, elems.get() );
        }

        return this.pushStack( ret );
    };
});
```